# Data Protocol URl

Tags: html, data-uri

What is a reliable way to use [data URIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI) for images? I know IE6/7 don't support them, so will this work?

1. I use data URIs for images by default
2. If browser is IE6/7 it shows the image (not as data but actual image) using javascript
3. include the image (not as data) in `<noscript>`.

My question is: will the image be fetched in `<noscript>` even if the browser supports javascript and data URIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do want to go down this road (and I personally would not bother), you *could* do it...

```
// Parse user agent and figure out if this browser supports data 
// URIs - e.g. `supportDataUri()`.  Also, store the image path
// somewhere - I'll assume for convenience an attribute called `data-image-src`

if ( ! supportDataUri()) {

   var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

   for (var i = 0, imagesLength = images.length; i < imagesLength; i++) {
       var imgSrc = images[i].getAttribute('data-image-src');
       images[i].src = imgSrc;
   }

}
```

Comment: "I personally would not bother"  - i have to display lot of small images should i still not bother and what about < no script > thing will it still be fetched

Comment: @Web Developer If you have heaps of small images, use CSS sprites.

Comment: i cant use css sprite as images are to be shown dynamically. anyways will be image be loaded in second case i.e fetched